# About consumer/product pattern

Tags: java

The following source code are used to implement product/consumer pattern, but they don't work well, and I don't know how to solve it.

class 1:productor

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Productor extends Thread {

private List list = null;

public Productor(ArrayList list) {
    this.list = list;
}

public synchronized void product() throws InterruptedException {
    for (int e = 0; e < 10; e++) {
        System.out.println("Add-" + e + "  " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        list.add(e);

        if (list.size() >= 10) {
            wait();
        } else {
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
}

public void run() {
    try {
        while(true){
            product();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

class 2:Consumer
    package test;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Consumer extends Thread {

private List list = null;

public Consumer(ArrayList list) {
    this.list = list;
}

public synchronized void consume() throws InterruptedException {
    if (list.size() <= 0) {
        wait();
    } else {
        notifyAll();
    }

    for (int e = 0; e < list.size(); e++) {
        System.out.println("Remove-" + e + "  "
                + System.currentTimeMillis());
        list.remove(e);
    }
}

public void run() {
    try {
        while(true){
            consume();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

class 3:Testing for product/consumer
    package test;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestCP {
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    ArrayList product = new ArrayList();
    Productor pt = new Productor(product);
    Consumer ct = new Consumer(product);
    pt.start();
    ct.start();
}
}
```

The output of TestCP is :

Add-0  1340777963967

Add-1  1340777963968

Add-2  1340777963968

Add-3  1340777963968

Add-4  1340777963968

Add-5  1340777963968

Add-6  1340777963968

Add-7  1340777963968

Add-8  1340777963968

Add-9  1340777963968

My intent is that Productor products 10 elements that stored in a list and consumed by Consumer, then Productor products elements again, Consumer consumes again...
Any feedback will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It would probably help if you said what they weren't doing properly, what they should be doing, and what you'd already tried to fix it. "They don't work well" is unhelpful to us.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "don't work well"? You are more likely to get a quality answer with a better phrased question.

Comment: What are you trying to do and what are u getting ?

Comment: PeterMmm's feedback is what I need, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wait/notify on the diferent thread not on the list. So the threads are running on their own monitors not on a shared one. Search for "java wait notify" and keep on reading.